# Invalid Aura API : Source

Tags: community

[image]

I don't understand this problem,please,tell me more about it.How I may decide this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `getCallback` and `setCallback`. Note the lowercase `b` instead of uppercase `B`. JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe.

Answer (score 1):

At line number 9, remove `$A.getCallBack` and try to save the helper js.
Below is the code snippet

```
action.setCallback(this,function(response){

// logic

}
```

`$A.getCallback()` is used when passing a callback function to a function outside the Lightning framework that might interact with a component outside the normal rendering lifecycle, such as setTimeout():